# speed up rendering a static scene with a moving camera

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a room and a moving camera inside. Everything is static, including lights. 
I am under the impression that there should be a way to theoretically speed up the rendering time tremendously, as ray tracing and other calculations are likely to be duplicated among individual frames. I may be totally mistaken and misunderstanding the basics of rendering though as I couldn't find any related questions in the forum.

Comment: Just use Baking.

Comment: [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU) is a tutorial on baking to speed up renders.

Comment: In the Performance Tab enable "Cache BVH"

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is yes, but first I would like to explain something.**

Cycles is what is called a [backwards ray tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)) engine.  This means that it sends photons (rays) *from the camera* instead of from light sources.  It then traces the ray backwards through the scene *until it hits a light source* or goes off into space, it then figures out what color that pixel should be based on what the ray hit.  You can read more in the Wikipedia article I linked.  But basically the jist is that rendering *as normal*, since the rays are coming from the camera (which is what is moving), you can't speed up rendering of a static scene.

But, there is a process called *texture baking* which allows you to tell blender to calculate the photons in the scene and “bake” what each object looks like to a texture, which you then assign to the object as an emission shader.  Then when you render your scene as normal it is only calculating emission shaders which is much faster.

Andrew Price has a very good tutorial on [getting started with cycles baking](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/#.VDVJfJUtDX4) that I recommend you watch.

Comment: Note that any shading which is affected by the camera location/direction, such as reflections, will look fake.

Comment: thanks so much for all these answers. Of course I tried to bake the meshes but I may do it wrong as i don't see improvements in the rendering processing time. I may add that the camera is not interfering with the rendered scene and that I am using blender render, not yet Cycles. I will carefully check these tutorials in the next few days.

Comment: @mat Once the render is baked to textures, you don't need to render using BI, you can just render with openGL displaying the baked textures.

Comment: @mat please in future mention which renderer you're using in the question itself (preferably the title) to avoid wasting peoples time.

Comment: @mat you can also use the blender-internal/cycles tags.